# How to pass a bool variable by reference in a non-bool function?

Tags: c++

I looked [at how to pass a bool by reference](http://cboard.cprogramming.com/cplusplus-programming/112625-passing-boolean-var-reference.html), but that function returned the bool inside of it. I also looked [here on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11932614/in-c-is-it-bad-to-pass-a-const-bool-by-reference), but the suggestions made by the commenters did not improve my situation. So,

I have a function:

```
myTreeNode* search_tree(myTreeNode *test_irater, char p_test, bool &flag)
```

That obviously returns a `myTreeNode*` type. I also have a variable, `bool flag` that I want to change the value of within the function. However, when I try to pass the bool by reference, I get an error message of

> error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'bool&'
>   from an rvalue of type 'bool*'|

How do I go about passing a bool by reference without returning a bool? I am running on the latest version of CodeBlocks, if that is relevant.

Edit: code

```
myTreeNode* search_tree(myTreeNode *test_irater, char p_test, bool &flag)
{
    switch(p_test) 
    {
    case 'a':
        if (test_irater->childA == NULL)
            flag = false;
        else {
            test_irater = test_irater->childA;
            flag = true;
        }
        break;
    case 't':
        if (test_irater->childT == NULL)
            flag = false;
        else {
            test_irater = test_irater->childT;
            flag = true;
        }
        break;
    case 'c':
        if (test_irater->childC == NULL)
            flag = false;
        else {
            test_irater = test_irater->childC;
            flag = true;
        }
        break;
    case 'g':
        if (test_irater->childG == NULL)
            flag = false;
        else {
            test_irater = test_irater->childG;
            flag = true;
        }
        break;
    }
    return test_irater;
}
```

called like:

```
test_irater = search_tree(test_irater, p_test, &flag);
```

Comment: Please show the code that produces this error.

Comment: I edited to show code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using the addressof(`&`) operator, meaning `&flag` is converted to `bool*`

Remove it, and it should work:

```
test_irater = search_tree(test_irater, p_test, flag);
```

Comment: the function works, but I don't think it is changing the value of `flag`.

Comment: @NickPredey it will work. If your function signature takes a reference, then it will get a reference to the argument you passed in. Here's a demo: http://ideone.com/tDKK0s

Comment: Okay, I will reevaluate my function and see if that is the problem.